# Alternative to FreeQ as functional programming

Tags: pattern-matching, functional-style

I wrote a code like this

```
ConstQ[expr_]:=FreeQ[expr,a|c]
```

in order to verify if some expression contains a or c. Let's call these a end c *variable to avoid*.

I want to write down something more functional-flavoured: I declare

```
VariableToAvoid[_]:= False;
VariableToAvoid[a|c]:= True.
```

and I would like to write a function which does the same as ConstQ neither writing all the variables to avoid inside it nor making VariableToAvoid function to build a list, which doesn't seem very much functional. I'm a bit stuck.
Can anyone help me?

## EXAMPLE

1) non functional method

```
FreeQ[CentralDot[a,c],a|c];
```

which return False

2) functional method

```
ToAvoid[_]:=False;
ToAvoid[a]:=True;
ToAvoid[c]:=True;
```

Now I want to get the same result as above on the a generic expression, in this case CentralDot[a,c] without list the variable to avoid

```
AreThereMyUglyVariablesQ[CentralDot[a,c]]
```

of course this function must contain some ToAvoid applied to the compoment of the internal exprssion, but I do not know how

Comment: How should your function know which variables to avoid? Could you give us an example of usage of such a function, i.e. the input you expect to give it, and the output you expect to receive?

Comment: @MarcoB I edited the question!

Comment: Does `ConstQ = FreeQ[a|c]` do what you want?

Comment: No, because I must insert manually the variable a and c, ad I do not want to.

Comment: You have to insert it some time, and with `ConstQ = FreeQ[a|c]` you only do it once. Then you can do `ConstQ[CentralDot[1,2]], ConstQ[CentralDot[a,c]]` and get `True`, `False`.

Comment: I know, but in my case I cannot do because the function ToAvoid must be present for other reason in other part of my code. And which is more important, at any point I must be able to declare other variables to avoid.

Comment: @MaPo If you find my answer fully satisfactory please consider accepting it.  If you do not please tell me what remains unaddressed and I shall try to improve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possibly you are looking for [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html):

```
ToAvoid[_] := False;
ToAvoid[a] := True;
ToAvoid[c] := True;

FreeQ[CentralDot[a, b], _?ToAvoid]

  (*  False  *)

FreeQ[CentralDot[x, y], _?ToAvoid]

  (*  True   *)
```

Comment: I like your solution more than mine! Thank you

Comment: @MaPo You are welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I found the anwser

```
Nor @@ ToAvoid /@ Level[expr, Infinity]
```

Comment: This is not a desirable way to write this operation, compared to `FreeQ`, as it requires exhaustively listing all parts of the expression (duplication), then testing *all* of them with `ToAvoid`.  `FreeQ` will simply scan the expression (without duplication) and it will exit early if possible.

Comment: Also you will need `Level[expr, Infinity, Heads -> True]` if you wish to match the default behavior of `FreeQ`.  To provide early exit you could use [`AnyTrue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnyTrue.html):  `! AnyTrue[Level[expr, Infinity, Heads -> True], ToAvoid]`